# get error while deploying maven+spring app in tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, cloudbees

i am trying to host a sample maven+spring app at cloudbees, it runs fine locally using mvn bees:run, i am yet to explore many cloudbees concepts, kindly help with getting ahead of this error in tomcat logs 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following dependency in your pom.xml

`<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: i have dependency added to pom, app works fine locally but when i deploy it at cloudbees it fails and throws this error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log.